# sql query filter rows that used in another table

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have three tables ...

Table 1 **messagetype**

Table 2 **businesschannel** with columns: idBusinessChannel,idsystem,idMessageType, direction

Table 3 **partnersystemmessages** with columns: 
idSystem,
idMessageType

I need to write a query that returns list of messagetype that exudes messages that already used by  partnersystemmessages(idSystem column) table and businesschannel(direction column).

I have the following query so far, that returns messagetype list but ignores  direction

```
SELECT    DISTINCT messagetype.*
FROM      messagetype
LEFT OUTER JOIN BUSINESSCHANNEL bc ON 
    bc.idMessageType = messagetype.idMessageType 
    AND bc.direction = 'out'
LEFT JOIN partnersystemmessages ON  
    messagetype.idMessageType = partnersystemmessages.idMessageType
      AND partnersystemmessages.idSystem = 522
WHERE     partnersystemmessages.idMessageType IS NULL
```

**UPDATE- adding sample data**

```
messagetype
+--------------+----------+
| idMessageType| Name     | 
+--------------+----------+
| 1            | SMTP     | 
| 2            | EDI      | 
| 3            | AS2      | 
| 4            | WED      | 
| 5            | IDOC     | 
| 6            | general  | 
+--------------+----------+



businesschannel 
+------------------------+----------+---------------+------------+
| idpartnersystemmessages| idsystem | idMessageType | direction| |
+------------------------+----------+---------------+------------+
| 1859                   | 522      |     2         |  in        |
| 5131                   | 522      |     1         |  out       |
| 1773                   | 522      |     2         |  out       |
| 1775                   | 522      |     3         |  in        |
| 1777                   | 522      |     4         |  out       |
| 4555                   | 522      |     5         |  in        |
+------------------------+----------+---------------+------------+
partnersystemmessages 
+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| idpartnersystemmessages |MessageidSystem | |idMessageType|
+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| 1859                    |   522          |     2        |
| 5131                    |   522          |     1        |  
| 1773                    |   522          |     2        | 
| 1775                    |   522          |     3        |  
| 1777                    |   522          |     4        |  
| 4555                    |   522          |     5        |  
--------------------------+----------------+--------------+
```

for idSystem = 522 and direction = 'out'
i am expecting:

```
 messagetype
+--------------+----------+
| idMessageType| Name     | 
+--------------+----------+
| 1            | SMTP     | 
| 3            | AS2      | 
| 5            | idoc     | 
| 6            | general  | 
+--------------+----------+
```

excluding EDI and WEB already in use for out direction

Comment: Hi! Could you try and add some data examples to your question? Maybe you could allso add an example fo the output you're getting and an illustration of your desired output. Would be great, thanks!

Comment: yeah i know its confusing,i will add more details

Comment: Does `messagetype` need to exclude BOTH other tables or just one or the other?

Comment: And why should SMTP be included in the results? And AS2 and IDOC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are joining two tables back to your main table that you need to exclude, add both conditions to your `WHERE`. The `LEFT JOIN.... IS NULL` pattern is usually pretty performant, though a `NOT EXISTS()` usually works very well, too, and might be the better choice. You'd have to test with your data.

**Full Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM messagetype mt
LEFT OUTER JOIN businesschannel bc ON bc.idMessageType = mt.idMessageType 
    AND bc.direction = 'out'
LEFT OUTER JOIN partnersystemmessages psm ON mt.idMessageType = psm.idMessageType
    AND psm.idSystem = 522
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/10661/2/0)**:

```
| idMessageType |    Name | idBusinessChannel | idsystem | idMessageType | direction | idSystem | idMessageType |
|---------------|---------|-------------------|----------|---------------|-----------|----------|---------------|
|             1 |    SMTP |                 2 |      522 |             1 |       out |      522 |             1 |
|             2 |     EDI |                 3 |      522 |             2 |       out |      522 |             2 |
|             2 |     EDI |                 3 |      522 |             2 |       out |      522 |             2 |
|             3 |     AS2 |            (null) |   (null) |        (null) |    (null) |      522 |             3 |
|             4 |     WED |                 5 |      522 |             4 |       out |      522 |             4 |
|             5 |    IDOC |            (null) |   (null) |        (null) |    (null) |      522 |             5 |
|             6 | general |            (null) |   (null) |        (null) |    (null) |   (null) |        (null) |
```

First, your original question seems to indicate that you want to exclude rows from `messagetype` that were matched to either `businesschannel` or `partnersystemmessages`. However your example results show rows limited to showing up in both.

***Use LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL**:*

```
SELECT DISTINCT mt.*
FROM messagetype mt
LEFT OUTER JOIN businesschannel bc ON bc.idMessageType = mt.idMessageType 
    AND bc.direction = 'out'
LEFT OUTER JOIN partnersystemmessages psm ON mt.idMessageType = psm.idMessageType
    AND psm.idSystem = 522
WHERE bc.idBusinessChannel IS NULL
    OR psm.idSystem IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/10661/2/1)**:

```
| idMessageType |    Name |
|---------------|---------|
|             3 |     AS2 |
|             5 |    IDOC |
|             6 | general |
```

***Use NOT EXISTS**:*

```
SELECT DISTINCT mt.*
FROM messagetype mt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM businesschannel bc 
    WHERE bc.direction = 'out'
        AND bc.idMessageType = mt.idMessageType 
  ) 
  OR NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM partnersystemmessages psm 
      WHERE psm.idSystem = 522
          AND psm.idMessageType = mt.idMessageType
  )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/10661/2/2)**:

```
| idMessageType |    Name |
|---------------|---------|
|             3 |     AS2 |
|             5 |    IDOC |
|             6 | general |
```

Changing the `OR`s to `AND`s limits the results further to only `general`. I'm still not clear why your original results included `SMTP`. My original query shows it was included in both tables. Was that a typo?

Comment: i just realized that i made  a mistake businesschannel table and partnersystemmessages  table.. updated sample data

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein Why did the `businesschannel` table change? Should that one have received a `idpartnersystemmessages` column?

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein Also, see my questions in the original post above.

Comment: i am loosing my mind over that data base ... i was trying your solution, and realized that  idMessageType  on BUSINESSCHANNEL not same is idMessageType  on messagetype so i updated my post .. messagetype need to exclude BOTH tables. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0):

try like below by changing join

```
SELECT    DISTINCT m.*
FROM      messagetype m
LEFT OUTER JOIN BUSINESSCHANNEL bc ON 
    bc.idMessageType = m.idMessageType 
       JOIN partnersystemmessages ON  
     bc.idsystem= partnersystemmessages.idsystem
      AND partnersystemmessages.idSystem = 522

WHERE     bc.idMessageType IS NULL
```